# Why aren't my rectangles showing?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, logic

I don't understand why my rectangles are not being shown.
I made the xaml, and data binded the canvas, and init properly.
What am I missing such that it only shows a blank screen.
It should show a digital figure 8.

MODEL:

```
namespace Final
{
    class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // define our property chage event handler, part of data binding
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // implements method for data binding to any and all properties
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }

        private double _topTopHorizontal;
        public double topTopHorizontal
        {
            get { return _topTopHorizontal; }
            set
            {
                _topTopHorizontal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("topTopHorizontal");
            }
        }

        private double _leftTopHorizontal;
        public double leftTopHorizontal
        {
            get { return _leftTopHorizontal; }
            set
            {
                _leftTopHorizontal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("leftTopHorizontal");
            }
        }


        public void initModel()
        {
            topTopHorizontal = 50;
            leftTopHorizontal = 50;
        }








    }
}
```

Main

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Model model;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // create an instance of our Model
            model = new Model();
            model.initModel();



        }






    }
}
```

Comment: You have put it inside the DataTemplate. Thats why it is not showing. What is your requirement?

Comment: a) You don't have a binding in your xaml. b) I don't understand the need for this contraption that you wrote: `Grid > Canvas > ItemsControl` and inside the `DataTemplate` again `Canvas > StackPanel > Canvas`. You don't have a list in your model, why do you need an ItemsControl?

Comment: At the moment I just want it to display the figure 8, I will use the data binded items later.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the DataContext for this window.

In constructor add:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new Model();

        DataContext = model;
    }
```

Therefor, your window can access "leftTopHorizontal" and "topTopHorizontal".

And in your xaml change:

```
Canvas.Top ="{Binding topTopHorizontal}"
Canvas.Left="{Binding leftTopHorizontal}"
```

with:

```
Canvas.Top ="{Binding model.topTopHorizontal}"
Canvas.Left="{Binding model.leftTopHorizontal}"
```